# warn: Please create an apidoc.json configuration file

Tags: npm, api-doc

I would like to use `apidoc` to create API documents, but in the implementation of `apidoc -i xcrm/ -o xcrm/apidoc/`command prompts the following error:

`warn: Please create an apidoc.json configuration file.
info: Nothing to do.`

But I created the file `apidoc.json` under public directory(my root directory).

```html
{
  "name": "xcrm",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "description": "apiDoc basic xcrm",
  "title": "xcrm API",
  "url" : "https://api.github.com/v1"
}
```

The apidoc website is http://apidocjs.com/

Answer (score 0):

Create an apidoc.json and add name property to the object.
{
  "name": "TestApp"
}

Comment: Please read the question.. "But I created the file apidoc.json under public directory(my root directory)."